# Import class items from csv into list

Tags: python, list, class, csv

I have a csv file that has about 4000 lines that look like this:

```
itemList.append(Item( 'SSCATALOG',  1,  "M" ,18 ,2))

itemList.append(Item( 'PTPC36200',  1,  "Z" ,19 ,8))
```

and a class that looks like this:

```
class Item:
  def __init__(self, pid, aisle, bay, hits, qtyPerOrder):
    self.pid = pid
    self.aisle = int(aisle)
    self.bay = bay
    self.hits = int(hits)
    self.qtyPerOrder = int(qtyPerOrder)
```

I'm trying to pull this data into a list called `itemList` using `jython`. Any help would be great.

Comment: Wasn't there supposed to be a question in your question?

Comment: Your "csv" doesn't look like CSV, it looks like Python code that assumes the existence of a list object called itemList.  It does not _import_ CSV, rather it's creating Item objects one per line and adding (appending) them to the list object at the same time.

Comment: Are you saying the `Item` class is in the same file with the `itemList.append(...)` lines?  Or is the one file that contains nothing but `append` lines and a separate file where the class is defined?

Comment: Did you mean to say that you have a csv file that contains data with these columns. And is your question: "How can I read this data and put it into a list of `Item` objects"?

Answer (score 0):

Your data does not look like comma-separated values (a CSV). Rather, it looks like partial Python code.
If your data file literally looks like this:

> itemList.append(Item( 'SSCATALOG',  1,  "M" ,18 ,2))
>
> itemList.append(Item( 'PTPC36200',  1,  "Z" ,19 ,8))

then you could use [exec](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement) to load it into your script:

```
class Item:
  def __init__(self, pid, aisle, bay, hits, qtyPerOrder):
    self.pid = pid
    self.aisle = int(aisle)
    self.bay = bay
    self.hits = int(hits)
    self.qtyPerOrder = int(qtyPerOrder)

with open('data', 'r') as f:
    itemList = []
    exec f
    print(itemList)
```

yields

```
[<__main__.Item instance at 0xb770cb4c>, <__main__.Item instance at 0xb770cb6c>]
```

Comment: You were being flippant, weren't you?

Comment: Actually, I wasn't. Sorry if it sounded that way. If importing does not work, I want the OP to say why. Then we have a question to answer.

Comment: That obviously won't work if the file doesn't define `itemList` or the `Item` class.

Comment: Only semi-flippant.  "A module is a file containing Python definitions and statements.", and the import statment would append ".py" to data.csv, and thus not find the file.  A brief search didn't find anything like a C #include that would literally insert a list of statements contained in a file.   But that alleged csv file does look a whole lot like #include-able Python code.

Comment: execfile() will allow to execute the Python fragment in the "csv" file, see my answer below.

Comment: Shame on you unutbu - you had a beautiful and funny response to the OP's obvious mistake (pasting a test harness instead of some actual csv), and now you've ruined it by getting all factual on us.

Answer (score 0):

Your data isn't CSV.  It's some sort of incomplete Python code.  From what you say, the easiest thing would be to add some code at the beginning of your data file, like this:

```
# add this
from someModule import Item
itemList = []

# leave the rest of your data below
itemList.append(Item( 'SSCATALOG',  1,  "M" ,18 ,2))
itemList.append(Item( 'PTPC36200',  1,  "Z" ,19 ,8))
# etc.
```

Here `someModule` is the Python module where the Item class is defined.  If you make these changes, you can then import your data file as a normal Python module and access its `itemList` variable to get at the data.

However, a better long-term solution would be to use a better data format.  Don't store the data like this:

```
itemList.append(Item( 'SSCATALOG',  1,  "M" ,18 ,2))
```

store it like this:

```
'SSCATALOG',1,"M" ,18,2
```

Then it will be a real CSV file.  You can import the data with [the `csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) and *then* create your objects then from the data you read in.  It's often better not to try to store an object of some user-defined class; instead, store the data you use to create that object, then recreate the object when you read in the data.  You could also look at [the `pickle` module](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) for reading and writing Python objects to files.

Answer (score -1):

There does not appear to be any actual CSV file involved in this question.

The code

```
 itemList.append(Item( 'SSCATALOG',  1,  "M" ,18 ,2))
```

does not contain comma separated values, notwithstanding that it has both values and commas, and the commas are between the values.  Instead, each line is creating an Item object (`Item( 'SSCATALOG',  1,  "M" ,18 ,2)`) and adding it to a list object called `itemList` (`itemList.append(. . .)`).

That code will perform the population of the list object provided you do two things before "calling" it:

- You must first create a list object called `itemList`
- You must make sure that your code has access to the definition of the `Item` class.

Assuming that `Item` is specified in a file called `item.py`, and the "csv" file with all the append statements is called pseudo_csv.py, you should be able to do this:

```
 import item
 itemList = []
 execfile('pseudo_csv.py')
```

Comment: This won't work unless you modify `pseudo_csv.py` to include at least some import statements.  Otherwise, `pseudo_csv.py` won't have access to the class and itemList defined outside.  Also, you need to do `import item` and `import pseudo_csv`, leaving off the ".py".

Comment: Correct on the import, but you can use execfile() to run the file directly without having to modify it.  Post is updated to reflect those corrections.